# Ensuring unlocking - case of unsupported/supported exception

Tags: c#, wcf, exception, locking

Lets consider a following piece of code:

```
lock(someObject) {
  try {

  }
  catch (...) {

  }
}
```

How to ensure that each this `lock` **always** will be released ? I mean some unsupported exceptions for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It'll be released as soon as the execution passes the outer brace of the lock.  The only way it won't get released is if the execution between the lock(x){ } never terminates e.g like...

```
lock(x)
{
   if (weAreCrazy)
   {
       while(true)
          Console.Writeline("Haven't we already done this?");
   }
}
<-- if (!weAreCrazy)... lock would be released here
```

Comment: So, what about non-supported exception ? Flow of code reach always `}` ?

Comment: It doesn't matter how the code exits the braces.... its similar to a using(y) { } statement, except a using statement calls dispose on y instead of releasing a lock

Comment: So in my case lock will be released. Thanks

Comment: Not just in your case, but every case... except the one mentioned above